# Unable to generate log with DailyRollingAppendar

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

`DailyRollingAppendar` for log for each minute has been configured.But only app.log getting generated but no further `app.log` generation with time after a minute.Tried with both `log4j1.2.16` & `1.2.17`, PLease help me where what else to be done

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, RollingAppender, stdout


# LOGFILE is set to be a DailyRollingFileAppender appender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=/Users/mine/Documents/Softwares/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/logs/app.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %C::%M()::%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Just to be sure you mean that you have nothing inside the file or that you have jsut one file?

Comment: only one file app.log getting generated.Expecting time to be appended to the file name after a min and new app.log to be generated

Comment: I can't figure out why it is not working the right way. Have you tried removing stdout temporarily? or rename your appender? Sorry for this poor help